# openCV basic_string::_S_construct null not valid

Tags: c++, opencv, eclipse-cdt

I am using openCV for the first time, I have followed the installation guide(for linux with eclipse CDT) and trying to run the sample program, but I keep getting the following error message.
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
  what():  basic_string::_S_construct null not valid

```
#include<cv.h>
#include<highgui.h>

using namespace cv;

int main( int argc, char** argv ){
Mat image;
image = imread( argv[1], 1 );

if( argc != 2 || !image.data )
{
    printf( "No image data \n" );
    return -1;
}

namedWindow( "Display Image", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
imshow( "Display Image", image );

waitKey(0);

return 0;
```

}

Comment: What's the question? You use `argv[1]` before checking for the error case `argc != 2`, so I'd start looking there if I were you. If `argc == 1` then `argv[1]` is null.

Comment: My guess is `argv[1]` happened to be null.

Comment: I am passing a the argument argv through eclipse by Run config, @SteveJessop you mean to check for argc before I use argv[1], I did that, but same problem.

Comment: @SteveJessop: It doesn't have some unspecified value, as being a non-existent element in the array?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: no it doesn't. `argv` is null-terminated and `argc` doesn't include the null.

Comment: @Steve: Outstanding. Found the same in 3.6.1/2.

Answer (score 0):

I got this same problem after finally getting my OpenCV libraries to link.  You are probably running the executable without an argument resulting in argv[1] to be Null when you try and do an image read.  The solution for me, on eclipse, was to call the file directly with an argument in command prompt; "testOpenCV.exe imageFile.png".  I obviously was using windows, but simply calling the executable with an argument, in terminal for your linux, should work.

Comment: That's a mouthful to just say "your argv[1] is null"